# iOS StoreKit returns invalidProductIdentifiers after upgrading app in sandbox

Tags: ios, app-store, in-app-purchase, storekit

I'm testing the upgrade process for one of my apps and I'm having trouble getting product info for my In App Purchases from the App Store.

I have two projects open in `XCode`, the first one is is code for my current build (2.0) and the other one is code for a working build (1.0) that was submitted to and approved by Apple.

1. I build and run 1.0
2. The app executes a product request:

   ```
   productRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers: productIds];
   productRequest.delegate = self;
   [productRequest start];
   ```
3. a response is returned with `SKProduct` instances (in response.products)
4. Then I build and run 2.0 in the other project
5. The app executes a product request
6. a response is returned, but all the product ids are retuned as invalid (in response.invalidProductIdentifiers)

HOWEVER... if I uninstall the app prior to running 2.0, everything works fine and `SKProducts` are returned as expected.

I've also gone through the same process with ad hoc builds instead of debug builds, but the behavior is identical.

All the project settings are identical in both projects except the App Version and Build.

So, there are two options.
Either there is something wrong with the StoreKit other than it being criminally non-verbose, or (more likely) I'm doing something wrong during my testing process.

Is it possible that there is some kind of sandbox mismatch (or something) due to the fact that I'm building one app over the other using different projects?

How would you test this scenario?

Comment: Seeing the same thing, but it's only on iOS 5.1.1.  My iOS 6 devices seem to work fine.

Comment: I realize this is a year later, but I encountered this issue when testing on iOS 5.1.1 as well. This post helped convince me I wasn't losing my mind. :)